# i want to separate Date and time format in json from laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-5.8

how are you ?

i have Laravel project and the json return date like this

2019-05-04

and time like this 
18:00:00

how can i make it like this

year : 2019

month : MAY

Day : 04

time : 06:00

timeS : PM

my code now is this

the model

```
public $table = 'bookings';

protected $dates = [
    'date',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
];

protected $fillable = [
    'date',
    'time',
    'user_id',
    'type_id',
    'persons',
    'order_no',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'table_cat_id',
    'booking_status_id',
];
```

the controller is

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(isset($user->id)){
        $bookings = Booking::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    }else{
        $bookings = null;
    }
    return response()->json($bookings);

}
```

Comment: Add your code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have added your code to the question, so i will try provide an answer using [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```php
//add this line to your controller:
use Carbon\Carbon;

//Parse the date you want to use:
$date = Carbon::parse($date); //Or use Carbon::now() to get the current time

$year  = $date->year;
$month = $date->format('F');
$day   = $date->day;
$timeS = $date->format('A');
$time  = $date->format('H:i');

//now return your json:

return response()->json([
    'year'  => $year,
    'month' => $month,
    'day'   => $day,
    'timeS' => $timeS,
    'time'  => $time,
]);
```

**Update**
To work with your code:
Choose the date you want to use, like `created_at` or `updated_at`.
Then, do something like this:

```php
//add this line to your controller:
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(isset($user->id)){
        $bookings = Booking::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

        //With the created_at field:
        foreach($bookings as $booking){
            $date  = Carbon::parse($booking->created_at);
            $year  = $date->year;
            $month = $date->format('F');
            $day   = $date->day;
            $timeS = $date->format('A');
            $time  = $date->format('H:i');

            $dates = array(
                'year'  => $year, 
                'month' => $month, 
                'day'   => $day, 
                'timeS' => $timeS, 
                'time'  => $time
            );

            $booking->dates = $dates;
        }
    }else{
        $bookings = null;
    }
    return response()->json($bookings);

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: not work with me i got "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (date) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database"

Comment: its work with me for current time but how can i use to change the date and time for $bookings

Comment: i change it to this and it's work 

                $date  = Carbon::parse($booking->date);
                $timea  = Carbon::parse($booking->time);
                $year  = $date->year;
                $month = $date->format('F');
                $day   = $date->day;
                $timeS = $timea->format('A');
                $time  = $timea->format('h:i');

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution**

You can append the `$dates` to your model.

To do it follow this steps:

1. Add the `$appends` to your model:

```php
protected $appends = ['dates'];
```

2. Use Carbon in your model:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

3. Create a `getDatesAttribute` function in your model (it is an accessor):

```php
public function getDatesAttribute()
{
    $date = Carbon::parse($this->created_at) //You can use any date field you want

    $year  = $date->year;
    $month = $date->format('F');
    $day   = $date->day;
    $timeS = $date->format('A');
    $time  = $date->format('H:i');

    return array (
        'year'  => $year, 
        'month' => $month, 
        'day'   => $day, 
        'timeS' => $timeS, 
        'time'  => $time
    );

}
```

4. Now, everytime you execute a query with your model, the `dates` will be include to the returned collection. You can access it with:

```php
$record->dates
```

> Note that `$record` is the just an example name.

Read more about [Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) here.